# python tensorflow import dll load failed

Tags: python, tensorflow, dll

I installed latest python 3.6.4 x64 version

and then installed tensorflow for cpu-only with pip3

```
C:\>pip3 install tensorflow
```

however when I tried to import tensorflow in python

it showed me the error below

I am sure that I have installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable(x64)

so it wll not be the problem of dll msvcp140.dll lost

it say that "DLL load failed with error code -1073741795"

so what is exactly the problem here

i cannot find any other information about this error code

my os : windows 7 enterprise with service pack 1 / 64 bit / intel core i5 M 540

```
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\t
ensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\Alan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__ini
t__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\t
ensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Alan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\t
ensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Alan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\t
ensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\Alan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__ini
t__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Alan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\t
ensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\Alan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\t
ensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Alan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\t
ensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\t
ensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\Alan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__ini
t__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\t
ensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Alan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\t
ensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Alan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\t
ensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\Alan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__ini
t__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_probl
ems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: [Can I ask questions about installation in SO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338203/can-i-ask-questions-about-installation-in-so) Questions about software tools commonly used by programmers must be **a practical, answerable problem unique to software development.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got same problem with tensorflow1.6-CPU on win7 64bit(Intel Core 2 Duo Cpu T6670 2.2GHz)

After I found this, and it solved my problem.

Reference this issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17386

Re-installed by this tensorflow-1.6.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl: https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel/tree/master/1.6.0/py36/CPU/sse2

Hope this .whl may help you.

Comment: Or try reinstall 1.5, pip install tensorflow==1.5

Comment: Do you know what changed in the code? Is it safe to install this?

Comment: Hi Ando, reference this issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17386

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue with tensorflow-1.12.0
what i did was :

1. Install anaconda
2. open anaconda prompt
3. `conda create -n tfp python=3.6`
4. `activate tfp`
5. `conda install tensorflow`
6. `python`
7. Now check by importing tensorflow

the version i used was 3.6, but you can also try with 3.7
Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.  My Anaconda install was version 5.2.0.  Installing tensorflow 1.12.0 through the Anaconda Navigator did not work, but doing it your way did.  I had to cd to C:\Users\Username\Anaconda3\Scripts for your line 5.

Answer (score 1):

I downgraded tensorflow to 1.10.0 and it fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

Probably, your CPU does not have the instructions for AVX (needed for all tensorflow binaries since 1.6). You can check that with some tool like CPU-Z. If that is the case, you can donwload the correct wheel here (use SSE2 binaries):

[tensorflow-windows-wheel](https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
I upgraded pip version with:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

also, downgraded with

```
pip install tensorflow==2.0
```

and it worked

Answer (score 0):

ImportError: DLL load failed
for
windows 10
python 3.6

```
 pip install protobuf==3.6.0
```

or

```
pip3 install protobuf==3.6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.
Spend days searching to fix them.

Installed tensorflow with `pip install tensorflow-cpu`
Updated visual C++ 2015-2019

The issue was because I didn't have nvidia graphics so that I should install with cpu version because I am using Radeon Vega 8 graphics.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried different methods still it doesn't work then I apply this method it works for me.

STOP  you antivirus protection software for half hour then install anaconda,it works fine. 100%

Answer (score 0):

If you use python 3.6.10 and tensorflow 2.1.0
Just follow this -

pip install tensorflow==2.0

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had first Upgraded the Anaconda prompt

I had then used conda create -n tfp python=3.7

conda activate tfp

Then import the tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue for tensorflow 2.0
First I uninstalled tensorflow using ***pip uninstall tensorflow*** (no need to uninstall tensorflow-estimator or tensorboard).
Then I reinstall using ***conda install tensorflow***.

Answer (score 0):

Never install the latest version of tensorflow it will raise an error
DLL file load error

```
pip install tensorflow
```

never run command on your computer as it not supports the tensorflow cpu
most of the latest version supports mostly gpu

so while installing install the lower version of the tensorflow
from my opininon the stable release of tensorflow  is tensorflow 1.5
make sure you uninstalled your tensorflow installed in your computer
pip uninstall tensorflow

After above step shutdown your pc and restart.Then only install tensorflow 1.5
command to install tensorflow version 1.5

```
pip install tensorflow==1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Install Microsoft Visual C++ 2019 Redistributable & reboot the PC, it will work with tensorflow 2.3.1 in python 3.7