# Tensorflow giving error ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using python 3.7, Tensorflow 1.14.0, keras 2.2.5 on Windows 7. When I run the project its throwing below error.

```
`Using TensorFlow backend.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "E:\Python\PycharmProjects\nFace\venv\lib\site- 
 packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
 from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
 File "E:\Python\PycharmProjects\nFace\venv\lib\site- 
 packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
 File "E:\Python\PycharmProjects\nFace\venv\lib\site- 
 packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
 File "C:\Users\sandip.d\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
 return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
 File "C:\Users\sandip.d\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 343, in 
 load_dynamic
 return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:`
```

I tried many solutions, I am new in Python and stack-overflow. I cant update tensorflow and keras version.

Comment: Is your system Windows 7?

Comment: @Johnny yes Windows 7..

Comment: Maybe you need this : Windows 7 SP1(Service Pack 1) KB976932

Comment: @Johnny manually I install from **https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=5842**, it didny work, any other solution

Comment: Does your CPU or gpu support the current version of tf?

Comment: @Johnny I need a current version only

Comment: I suspect that your CPU does not support AVX instruction sets. You can check [hardware requirements](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?lang=python3#hardware-requirements). To fix above issue you can create virtual environment on windows and install tensorflow. You may also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49113497/python-tensorflow-import-dll-load-failed). Thanks!