# Import Error for tensor, keras error code -1073741795

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

When I run this code:

```
import math
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
```

I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Family\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Family\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Family\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Family\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Family\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I have tensorflow 2.0 already installed and am using python 3.7.3

I have found multiple problems like these online but none for them work for me. Any help will be dearly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: have you tried to change python version?

Comment: no. Which version should I go for?

Comment: try python 3.6.Let me know.

Comment: I suspect that your CPU does not support AVX instruction sets. You can check [hardware requirements](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?lang=python3#hardware-requirements). To fix above issue you can create [virtual environment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25468#issuecomment-469390772) on windows and install tensorflow. You may also refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49113497/python-tensorflow-import-dll-load-failed,Thanks!